# String not equal to another string. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, hexdump

More specifically, how to test further? I saw another post where the answer used a hexdump.  How might I try this, and should I?

Here's my trying in console...

variables: myl is my latitude value from my database.  ul is the value from an api. ll is where I hand retyped the value:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :106 > myl=a.latitude   #=> "42.3471841"
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :107 > ul=@events[30].xpath('venue')[0]['lat']
=> "42.3471836"
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :108 > myl==ul   #=> false
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :109 > myl==ul.to_i   #=> false
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :110 > myl.to_i==ul.to_i   #=> true
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :111 > Venue.find_by_latitude(ul)   #=> nil
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :112 > Venue.find_by_latitude(ul.to_i)   #=> nil
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :113 > Venue.find_by_latitude(ul.to_s)   #=> nil
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :114 > ul   #=> "42.3471836"
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :115 > myl.class   #=> String
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :116 > ul.class   #=> String
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :117 > ll="42.3471836"   #=> "42.3471836"
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :118 > myl==ll   #=> false
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :119 > ul==ll   #=> true
```

Any suggestions would be most helpful! The goal is to use latitude and longitude to identify a place already stored in my database, since names of a place are not always unique.

Comment: Keep in mind `.to_i` will round down. `"42.3471841".to_i` is `42`.

Comment: @tadman: Well, it does answer everything, doesn't it?

Comment: What's with the downvote? Sure, it's not worded entirely clearly, but this place is for helping people out, right? No matter how much or little experience they have.

Comment: +1 for the question :)   `.to_i` is definitely not what you want!  use `.to_f` instead.  You should then compare the Floats, not Strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

As I understand it, you're envisioning these things as numbers, not strings, so it's probably best to convert them before you make the comparison.

Second, since the strings aren't really equal, but fairly close as latitudes go, I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you're really trying to compare them with some allowed margin of error. Like so (assuming `myLatitude` and `apiLatitude` are numbers):

`(myLatitude - apiLatitude).abs < 0.000001`

And (while you're at it) make sure that your longitude convention (-180 to 180 vs. 0 to 360) is consistent when you're comparing those.

Comment: thanks, this should help compare mostly similar latitudes in the future

Comment: Significant digits is a bit of a misnomer here if you're doing string hacking. A negative number will have precision reduced by one digit.

Comment: @tadman - You're right; that point actually illustrates why these things shouldn't be dealt with as strings. I'm removing that from my answer.

Comment: Using a margin of error like that is a much better solution, and you can adjust it in the future. Good call.

Answer (score 1):

`myl = "42.3471841"`
`ul = "42.3471836"`
`ll = "42.3471836"`

Of course myl is not equal to ul (they contain different string values), but ul and ll are equal (they contain the same string value).  I dont understand what your question is?  Your code shows why myl isnt equal to ll

Comment: derp! thanks for pointing that out.  I assumed since I grabbed from same data source a few days earlier they would be the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with the values stored being different enough that an exact match won't work. This often comes into play when you're dealing with varying levels of precision.

You may want to switch to a convention where all values are forced to a particular level of precision before being saved. For instance, fix them before saving:

```
def set_precision
  self.latitude = '%.6f' % self.latitude.to_f
  self.longitude = '%.6f' % self.longitude.to_f
end
```

This will convert values like `"42.72"` into `"42.720000"` as well as trimming excessively precise values.

When searching, just apply the same formatting.